# is there Any WP plugin which will display my Buddypress members age, Gender & Analytics Report?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

is there Any WP plugin which will display my Buddypress members age, Gender & Analytics Report?
i have a wordpress dating sites that uses bubbypress for it's social network software but it does not have a statistical report for the members who uses the site. I am looking for someone to create a widget or something on my admin dashboard to keep a statistic report of the members who register to use the site and are members, i would like to know the number of members the gender and age of the members to keep track of.

Answer (score 0):

yes

Buddypress Who clicked at my Profile?

[download link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress-who-clicked-at-my-profile/)

This plugin will notify your members about other members that visited their profile via buddypress notification system.
This plugin also provides a widget that shows last profile visitors for the logged in user.
This plugin provides a shortcode that can be used anywhere to display the logged in user’s visitors

Shortcode usage:

```
[buddypresswcamp_show_visits]
```